# Meta tag and Script processing inside URL

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, xss

I am currently studying about session fixation techniques and read this article about it:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation

In example 2 and 3, it states that I can presumably set the cookie of a user that loads a resource using the following URLS:

```
http://website.kom/<script>document.cookie=”sessionid=abcd”;</script>
http://website.kon/<meta http-equiv=Set-Cookie content=”sessionid=abcd”>
```

Does this mean that the browser processes these tags when processing URLS? I have tried executing scripts embedded in urls that load iframes and could not get them to execute even when I url encoded the script tags.

**EDIT**

I also think that the problem would be when the url is displayed to other users and the script executes. However, the nature of session fixation is having a user's cookie set by an attacker prior to log in in order for the attacker to hijack the session when the user logs in. This is in contrast to usual XSS attacks that attempts to steal the user's cookie to hijack the session. If that is the case, should not the user be at the target site first in order for the above scripts to change the browser cookies for the target site? In my understanding, browser cookies is a per site basis. So if the above script executes in any other site aside from the target site, the cookies would be set to the site the user is currently on and not to the target site. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you type something like this in the Browser's url bar:

```
http://example.com/<script>alert("Hello World");</script>
```

It is treated as

```
http://example.com/%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22Hello%20World%22%29;%3C/script%3E
```

The plain url should do nothing in a browser. If a browser would show you an alert with the text "Hello World", this browser is a security hole and should never be installed somewehere.

However, if you are trying to create a dynamic page (JS/PHP/C#/Java etc), you should always remember, never trust the client.

If you would output the `{RequestURI}`, which is everything after `http://example.com/` you would have a problem. You should always encode Html Entities in user inputs, or use some filter, that disallow `<meta>`, `<script>` and anything that could have problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I also think that the problem would be when the url is displayed to other users and the script executes. However, the nature of session fixation is having a user's cookie set by an attacker prior to log in in order for the attacker to hijack the session when the user logs in. If that is the case, should not the user be at the target site first in order for the above scripts to change the browser cookies for a particular site?

Comment: I have updated my question to include further details.